# How to pass keyword to background process to close properly?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, crontab

I have just created a shell script and and added to `crontab -e`

Crontab is working fine but when I kill process manually the recorded video of that process is not playable.

Because when I run the application from the terminal and close that application by pressing <kbd>q</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> the recorded video of that application is playable but not when we kill the process.

The application is Deepstream application that get input from RTSP camera and output stream in RTSP and record that video. To kill the process I use `sudo kill PID` and`sudo pkill process-name` but this will make the recorded video unplayable.

How to solve this problem?

if I run in terminal and close with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
the recorded video will be playable.

```
$ sudo deepstream-app -c source8_1080p_dec_infer-resnet_tracker_tiled_display_fp16_nano.txt 
[sudo] password for mindnotice: 

 *** DeepStream: Launched RTSP Streaming at rtsp://localhost:8554/ds-test ***

Opening in BLOCKING MODE 
Opening in BLOCKING MODE 
gstnvtracker: Loading low-level lib at /opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-6.0/lib/libnvds_nvmultiobjecttracker.so
gstnvtracker: Batch processing is ON
gstnvtracker: Past frame output is ON
[NvMultiObjectTracker] Initialized
0:00:03.299363263 11754     0x18710b20 INFO                 nvinfer gstnvinfer.cpp:638:gst_nvinfer_logger:<primary_gie> NvDsInferContext[UID 1]: Info from NvDsInferContextImpl::deserializeEngineAndBackend() <nvdsinfer_context_impl.cpp:1900> [UID = 1]: deserialized trt engine from :/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-6.0/samples/models/tao_pretrained_models/latest-yolov4/yolov4_resnet18_epoch_070.etlt_b1_gpu0_fp16.engine
INFO: [Implicit Engine Info]: layers num: 5
0   INPUT  kFLOAT Input           3x384x1248      
1   OUTPUT kINT32 BatchedNMS      1               
2   OUTPUT kFLOAT BatchedNMS_1    200x4           
3   OUTPUT kFLOAT BatchedNMS_2    200             
4   OUTPUT kFLOAT BatchedNMS_3    200             

0:00:03.313609834 11754     0x18710b20 INFO                 nvinfer gstnvinfer.cpp:638:gst_nvinfer_logger:<primary_gie> NvDsInferContext[UID 1]: Info from NvDsInferContextImpl::generateBackendContext() <nvdsinfer_context_impl.cpp:2004> [UID = 1]: Use deserialized engine model: /opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-6.0/samples/models/tao_pretrained_models/latest-yolov4/yolov4_resnet18_epoch_070.etlt_b1_gpu0_fp16.engine
0:00:03.328004320 11754     0x18710b20 INFO                 nvinfer gstnvinfer_impl.cpp:313:notifyLoadModelStatus:<primary_gie> [UID 1]: Load new model:/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-6.0/samples/configs/deepstream-app/nvinfer1_config.txt sucessfully

Runtime commands:
    h: Print this help
    q: Quit

    p: Pause
    r: Resume

** INFO: <bus_callback:194>: Pipeline ready

Opening in BLOCKING MODE 
NvMMLiteOpen : Block : BlockType = 279 
NVMEDIA: Reading vendor.tegra.display-size : status: 6 
NvMMLiteBlockCreate : Block : BlockType = 279 
** INFO: <bus_callback:180>: Pipeline running

NvMMLiteOpen : Block : BlockType = 4 
NvMMLiteOpen : Block : BlockType = 8 
===== NVMEDIA: NVENC =====
===== NVMEDIA: NVENC =====
NvMMLiteBlockCreate : Block : BlockType = 4 
NvMMLiteBlockCreate : Block : BlockType = 8 
H264: Profile = 66, Level = 0 
NVMEDIA: H265 : Profile : 1 
NVMEDIA_ENC: bBlitMode is set to TRUE 
NVMEDIA_ENC: bBlitMode is set to TRUE 

**PERF:  FPS 0 (Avg)    
**PERF:  58.13 (52.30)  
**PERF:  31.18 (31.90)  
**PERF:  24.95 (28.51)  
^C** ERROR: <_intr_handler:140>: User Interrupted.. 

Quitting
[NvMultiObjectTracker] De-initialized
App run successful
mindnotice@ubuntu:/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-6.0/samples/configs/deepstream-app$ ps ax |grep deepstream
11890 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto deepstream
mindnotice@ubuntu:/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-6.0/samples/configs/deepstream-app$ sudo deepstream-app -c source8_1080p_dec_infer-resnet_tracker_tiled_display_fp16_nano.txt 

 *** DeepStream: Launched RTSP Streaming at rtsp://localhost:8554/ds-test ***

Opening in BLOCKING MODE 
Opening in BLOCKING MODE 
gstnvtracker: Loading low-level lib at /opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-6.0/lib/libnvds_nvmultiobjecttracker.so
gstnvtracker: Batch processing is ON
gstnvtracker: Past frame output is ON
[NvMultiObjectTracker] Initialized
0:00:03.177978493 11892     0x30168b20 INFO                 nvinfer gstnvinfer.cpp:638:gst_nvinfer_logger:<primary_gie> NvDsInferContext[UID 1]: Info from NvDsInferContextImpl::deserializeEngineAndBackend() <nvdsinfer_context_impl.cpp:1900> [UID = 1]: deserialized trt engine from :/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-6.0/samples/models/tao_pretrained_models/latest-yolov4/yolov4_resnet18_epoch_070.etlt_b1_gpu0_fp16.engine
INFO: [Implicit Engine Info]: layers num: 5
0   INPUT  kFLOAT Input           3x384x1248      
1   OUTPUT kINT32 BatchedNMS      1               
2   OUTPUT kFLOAT BatchedNMS_1    200x4           
3   OUTPUT kFLOAT BatchedNMS_2    200             
4   OUTPUT kFLOAT BatchedNMS_3    200             

0:00:03.190724954 11892     0x30168b20 INFO                 nvinfer gstnvinfer.cpp:638:gst_nvinfer_logger:<primary_gie> NvDsInferContext[UID 1]: Info from NvDsInferContextImpl::generateBackendContext() <nvdsinfer_context_impl.cpp:2004> [UID = 1]: Use deserialized engine model: /opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-6.0/samples/models/tao_pretrained_models/latest-yolov4/yolov4_resnet18_epoch_070.etlt_b1_gpu0_fp16.engine
0:00:03.204207961 11892     0x30168b20 INFO                 nvinfer gstnvinfer_impl.cpp:313:notifyLoadModelStatus:<primary_gie> [UID 1]: Load new model:/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-6.0/samples/configs/deepstream-app/nvinfer1_config.txt sucessfully

Runtime commands:
    h: Print this help
    q: Quit

    p: Pause
    r: Resume

** INFO: <bus_callback:194>: Pipeline ready

Opening in BLOCKING MODE 
NvMMLiteOpen : Block : BlockType = 279 
NVMEDIA: Reading vendor.tegra.display-size : status: 6 
NvMMLiteBlockCreate : Block : BlockType = 279 
** INFO: <bus_callback:180>: Pipeline running

NvMMLiteOpen : Block : BlockType = 8 
NvMMLiteOpen : Block : BlockType = 4 
===== NVMEDIA: NVENC =====
===== NVMEDIA: NVENC =====
NvMMLiteBlockCreate : Block : BlockType = 8 
NvMMLiteBlockCreate : Block : BlockType = 4 
H264: Profile = 66, Level = 0 
NVMEDIA: H265 : Profile : 1 
NVMEDIA_ENC: bBlitMode is set to TRUE 
NVMEDIA_ENC: bBlitMode is set to TRUE 

**PERF:  FPS 0 (Avg)    
**PERF:  54.25 (50.33)  
**PERF:  30.69 (31.71)  
**PERF:  25.00 (28.45)  
**PERF:  24.90 (27.32)  
**PERF:  25.04 (26.75)  
**PERF:  24.96 (26.40)  
**PERF:  24.95 (26.17)  
**PERF:  25.00 (26.00)  
**PERF:  25.05 (25.88)  
**PERF:  24.90 (25.78)  
Terminated
```

Comment: Which video recorder is it?

Comment: How do you kill the process?

Comment: this is deepstream application that get input from rtsp camera and output stream in rtsp and record that video.

Comment: @RomeoNinov  i use  
sudo kill PID
and sudo pkill process-name

Comment: Welcome to the community :-) Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1768756/edit) your question instead of answering in comments. This keeps the relevant data readily available for community members. I added the new info for you now. Please clarify the statement _I use `sudo kill PID and`_.

Comment: @Peregrino69 You are welcome

Comment: Now that should be helpful for the people in the know :-)

Answer (score 1):

To terminate a background process in a manner similar to pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, you can send the **SIGINT** signal to the process using the **kill** command. The SIGINT signal is the signal that is sent to a process when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> in the terminal.

Closing Background process in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> manner.

Step1:

```bash
ps ax | grep process-name
```

it will give you a list of processes to get a process ID.

Step2:

```bash
 sudo kill  -SIGINT  PID
```

Now I got closed my process and the video is playable.wow